# Export data from a User control to Excel Sheet in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, export-to-excel

I have a User control which contains data , basically like questions and answers (with yes or no options). Now I want to export the entire data from the User control to Excel sheet on clicking a button. How can I achieve this?
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: As of now I am unaware of how to approach this. I have done something like exporting a grid view to excel earlier. But not something like this. I am stil searching for a solution over here.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a structure containing `table` `tr` and `td` and then you can export it to excel.
Other wise if you have a `datatable` or `collection` like source only then you can export it to excel. 
You will have to write `function` to change your `user-control` to collection and then you can export it to excel.

Here is a sample code

```
<table id="mytable" runat="server">
    <tr ><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    </table>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment;filename=myexcel.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    mytable.RenderControl(hw);
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();

}
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{

}
```

Comment: Could you share a link to such a sample scenario?

Comment: Thanks for the sample. Let me try this code and see how it goes. Well I don't know who down voted it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code that I use to do it.

```
public class ExcelUtility
{
    public static void ToExcel(object dataSource)
    {
        GridView grid = new GridView { DataSource = dataSource };
        grid.DataBind();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (TableCell cell in grid.HeaderRow.Cells)
            sb.Append(string.Format("\"{0}\",", cell.Text));
        sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
        sb.AppendLine();

        foreach (GridViewRow row in grid.Rows)
        {
            foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
                sb.Append(string.Format("\"{0}\",", cell.Text.Trim().Replace("&nbsp;", string.Empty)));
            sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
            sb.AppendLine();
        }
        ExportToExcel(sb.ToString());
    }

    private static void ExportToExcel(string data)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Report.csv");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1255");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(data);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```